# Not able to fetch employee details in web api using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am developing one web api application using angularjs. I am doing one small crud operation. I am not able to hit to controller when debugging. Below is my controll.js code.

```
$scope.EditSubscriber = function (sub) {
        var servCall = UserCreation.getSubsbyID(sub.user_id);
        servCall.then(function (d) {
            $scope.user_email = d.user_email,
            $scope.user_password = d.user_password
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while fetching the data.')
        });
    }
```

Below is my service.js code.

```
  this.getSubsbyID = function (user_id) {
        return $http({
            method: 'get',
            data: JSON.stringify(user_id),
            url: 'api/User_Creation/' + user_id,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

This is my controller code.

```
public IEnumerable<Noor_Users> Get(int user_id)
        {
            return entityObject.Noor_Users.Where(a => a.user_id == user_id).AsEnumerable();
        }
```

I am not getting any error but I am not able to hit breakpoint in controller. May I know where I am doing wrong? Thank you all.

Comment: May i know why're you passing a json string to backend since it accept integer.

Comment: Thank you. I want to send integer because user_id is an integer.

Comment: Oh.. If you want to send integer just parse the user_id to int then. Can you paste the code where are the controller getting called?

Comment: Thank you. Here i am calling controller.   url: 'api/User_Creation/' + user_id from service.js file.

Comment: No, i mean where do you call $scope.EditSubscriber , whether in your view or controller

Comment: As @digit has stated, there's no need to stringify the int, just pass it as an int otherwise it won't be recognized by the signature of your api endpoint.

Comment: Sorry... I am calling it from index.cshtml as below.  <input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" ng-click="EditSubscriber(sub)" />

Comment: also i found one error. When i hit below url http://localhost:26079/api/User_Creation/9  I am supposed to get user details whose user_id is 9 but I am getting all the users.

Comment: I guess an integer issue has solve your question? That's your backend issue not angular.

Comment: Now i am able to hit to server. i just changed usr_id to id. but my  servCall.then(function (d) {
            alert(d); is not working.

Comment: i just changed as servCall.then(function (data) {
            $scope.sub = data.data;
            $scope.user_email = sub.user_email, and now started working fine.